# Matrix shapes difference between lectures

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

I'm currently learning deep-learning from two lectures. What gets me confused is that there is a notation difference between two lectures when they shape an input matrix X.

In Coursera's lecture, they make a matrix X in shape of (number of features, number of samples), so that they stack the samples vertically. Otherwise, the other lecture stacks the samples horizontally, so that every row represents one sample.

What makes this difference and which one should I follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple things to unpack here:

**First** Lets first assume that we only have one layer in our neural network and only one sample in the batch, you would stack the features vertically because it's intuitive that way,
[image: Neural Network basic structure]

As in the above Image it looks like each feature will be represented by an Input Node, so if you have multiple samples in the set, it makes sense to arrange them in shape of (number of features, number of samples), Before moving on to the next part be sure that you understand this part correctly.

**Part 2** Now when we want to move to the next layer, we want to make it look like the output of previous layer is the Input to this layer, so we want the input to be shaped as (number of hidden layers, number of samples), so that we visualize it with consistency for each layer, now we also have to feed forward, and for that in our Weight matrix of hidden layer we have the shape (No of features/Neurons in previous layers, No of features/Neurons  in Current layer), now to maintain consistency, we have to transpose Weight Matrix (W) before multiplying to X. I hope that explains why we stack samples Columns.

Now we move to why they are sometimes represented as stacked horizontally, And the answer is because then computing cost and loss is more Intuitive, you have your output layer y stacked as a vertical column, and your predictions y_hat as vertical columns, which makes statements like y - y_hat way more intuitive than if they were stacked horizontally and not as a vector.

So what should learn from this, while training feeding Inputs, we stack them as (number of features, number of samples) to maintain consistency and Intuitiveness throughout the network and we stack the samples vertically to obtain Y as a vector. In practice people generally avoid stacking samples vertically they just obtain the transpose of y or you output vector from the horizontal stack, but it is good to have that visualization in the starting.

**Edit**
Also to represent the Input data, e.g. when it's represented in a tabular structure like excel, csv, Dataframe etc. samples are stacked vertically.

If you have any confusion/Doubts, comment below.

Image Source: Google

Answer (score 0):

Both ways are fine, it only matters to be consistent, i.e., that all matrix operations are correct. Depending on the shape of the matrix you might have `matrix*vector` or `vector_transposed*matrix`, or some variety along these lines.

Playing around with different representations might actually help the understanding in the long run. So I would recommend to follow both lectures and appreciate the differences in how they represent the data etc.